# Black hole singularity from collapsing light vs dust

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, singularities

Consider two black holes, one formed from a spherical cloud of electromagnetic radiation, and one formed from a non-interacting dust solution.

The stress energy tensor is traceless for electromagnetic radiation, and has a non-zero trace for dust.  So the Ricci curvature scalar is $R=0$ inside the collapsing cloud for electromagnetism and non-zero for dust.

Are the resulting singularities somehow distinct?  Does the geometry have an infinite $R$ at the singularity for the dust case but not the electromagnetic case, and does this "boundary" condition affect the solution outside the singularity?

Comment: In your last sentence, do you really mean infinite $R$ in the case of electromagnetic radiation, or did you express that backwards?

Comment: General relativity is an incomplete theory. It doesn't "know" that electromagnetic radiation and matter can be converted into each other, it can therefor not describe what happens on the way to the singularity.

Comment: @RedAct, oops yes, I mistyped that.  But you understood what I meant from context though. Thanks.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand that discussing the singularity is beyond the applicability of the theory to the actual physics of the universe. This question is only about the properties of General Relativity from a theoretical model perspective.  So whatever the theory of quantum gravity may be, it is not an issue or relevant to this question.  I hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: I wasn't talking about quantum gravity, at all, merely about quantum field theory in (almost) flat backgrounds. In your scenario light would be converted to matter in strong gravity long before it would ever hit the singularity... but general relativity can simply not describe that conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat, I don't know. But I do know how to find out the answer.

In GR, one is allowed to make use of singularity theorems to classify singularities into different types. The best place to study this in my opinion is the book by [Ellis and Hawking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521099064) which is very mathematical but as my professor told me, "*If you can work it out, then you have mastered the universe*." Singularities are defined in terms of geodesic incompleteness i.e. all paths in spacetime which intersect this point, end at that point. However, GR cannot qualitatively or quantitatively describe the singularity and I think you agree with this from your comment. However, it does allow us to differentiate the kinds of singularities that may form in the universe. In fact, why singularities occur is an open problem in GR (i.e. How and why can smooth Cauchy data evolve into singular solutions?).

We have **scalar curvature singularities** i.e. when at least one scalar polynomial constructed from $R_{ab}, \ g_{ab}, T_{ab}$ diverges. Such singularities occur when either the Ricci tensor or Riemann tensor or both diverge. As far as my knowledge goes, I am not sure if whether singular solutions with derivatives of these tensors are allowed to form singular solutions i.e. I don't know about the dynamic nature of singularities. In this case you can have either the Ricci scalar to be divergent or the Riemann tensor to be divergene. Divergence of $R_{ab}$ implies that the stress energy tensor is divergent and the prime example of this is the Big Bang in the FLRW cosmology.

We also have the divergence of the Riemann tensor as in the case of black hole singularities, but the Ricci tensor is regular. And as you pointed out, $R=0$ for the case of Schwarzschild singularities.

We also have the case where both $R_{ab}R^{ab}$ and  $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$ diverge as in the case of RN black holes.

So with some of this information, all you would need to answer your problem is to check whether the Riemann tensor, Ricci tensor and stress energy tensor are regular at $r = 0$. And if not, you can differentiate them along the classification scheme I have very briefly outlined about. I should also mention that there are other possible singularities which I have not mentioned here. But if you are interested more about this, then I would recommend Ellis and Hawking's book. The complete categorisation of singularities is still an open problem.

Hope this answer is of some use to you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by checking whether something is "regular at r=0". Maybe this isn't the best analogy, but consider classical electromagnetism and a point charge. The charge density is zero everywhere but r=0. I can't just say the limit shows the charge density is zero at r=0. Instead I can use Gauss's law to argue there is charge at the r=0 singularity. So while for Schwarzschild black holes R=0 at every point r>0, I'm not sure if we can claim R=0 at the point r=0. Basically I was curious if R≠0 at the singularity for collapsing dust but R=0 when considering collapsing light.

Comment: Checking something is regular means you calculate the quantity and check if there are no infinities which occur in a certain limit. The analogy of EM does not hold here in this particular sense. For Schwarzschild black holes, the Ricci scalar vanishes everywhere, even at $r = 0$, so $R$ is regular as $r \rightarrow 0$. What you should check is that for the different cases, you have the metric: Look at the value of the Ricci scalar as $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I understand looking at the limit as $r\to 0$, but I don't understand the step where you say "Ricci scalar vanishes everywhere, even at $r=0$".  How can we see that? @Timaeus below also suggests that we cannot calculate or meaningfully discuss what value $R$ has at $r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a spherically symmetric shell of dust with Minkowksi spacetime on the inside.

So as you track the surface of falling dust, it has curvature on the surface (but not a tiny bit inside the surface) and there is no curvature at the origin up until the dust surface hits it. But that's the same point when then the curvature on the dust surface goes through the roof. And the curvature already jumped at the dust surface.

If the curvature of the two is the same outside then they both blow up the way as the collapsing surface hits the singularity. But the singularity isn't a place with properties. They are places missing from the manifold that can not be put in.

> the solutions are the same for r>0,

They are the same about he source and below the source. The source is collapsing, eventually the source reaches $r=0$ which is *not a place*.

> we cannot meaningfully ask about properties of the manifold at r=0.

There is no manifold when $r=0.$

> is there an actual mathematical consequence to claiming the singularity at r=0 is removed from the manifold, and so we must say it is removed?

If you tried to extend the manifold to include the excluded events, you could make manifolds that agree away from the singularity but are different manifolds. So there isn't *a* manifold there. And it doesn't make sense to talk about *the* manifold at those events.

Comment: To make sure I understand, the summary is: the solutions are the same for r>0, and we cannot meaningfully ask about properties of the manifold at r=0.  Seems reasonable, but I'd prefer to say there is a singularity in the curvature at r=0 than to claim r=0 somehow was actually removed from the manifold.  At this point is this just a matter of wording, or is there an actual mathematical consequence to claiming the singularity at r=0 is removed from the manifold, and so we must say it is removed?